# The conda command cannot be executed because it cannot read the entire user path

Tags: python, path, anaconda, windows-10, environment-variables

Before a few days ago I had been using Anaconda for a long time (about one year) and there were no problems, but lately I can't use the anaconda command (such as `conda activate` or only `activate`).

[conda activate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T79fP.png)

Every time I run Anaconda the command prompt goes unrecognized because it is unable to read the entire user path.

[Anaconda Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnEKU.png)

The user path should read `C:\Users\Yusuf's PC`, but it only read `C:\Users\Yusuf's`. When I tried other commands using CMD for example `git init` it didn't have any problems.

[git init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRxH6.png)

However, it's different when I just use the `conda` command without any arguments. It runs normally (it displays command help just like other commands running on CMD).

[conda command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onChO.png)

I have tried to add Anaconda to environment variables in control panel but nothing changes.

[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TffVV.png)

n.b.: I installed Anaconda on `D:\anaconda3`

I have also tried to reinstall Anaconda, but it doesn't work either.

Is there any help? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Please post text, not images. Read [ask] and [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: I can't post images yet, because I don't have enough reputation

Comment: what keeps you from copying and pasting the screen's contents **as text**?